# Adding a list into a list

Tags: c#, list

My code works as expected except for when I add a playerHand, which is a list of cards, to a playerHands list, it changes all previous player hands in the list to the current playerHand.

My thought as to what is happening is that there is only one playerHand in memory which is constantly being updated with dealt cards. The items in playerHands list are simply pointing to that single playerHand.

**How do I create multiple instances of playerHand so that each item in the playerHands list is unique?**

Note: my initial reaction was to use Arrays instead of List, but as far as I can tell Arrays are old-school and deprecated in favor of List.
Solving my problem is my goal here but if there are any thoughts as to the direction I am taking with this program would be accepted.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Blackjack
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int numOfDecks = 2;
            List<Cards> shoe = Deck.createDeck(numOfDecks);
            Deck.shuffleDeck(shoe, numOfDecks);
            Hand  playerHand  = new Hand();
            Hands playerHands = new Hands();

            //Test Hands
            //Create ten hands of dealt cards
            for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
            {               
                playerHand.clearHand();
                playerHands.addHand(playerHand);
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                 {
                    playerHand.addCard(shoe[j]);
                    shoe.RemoveAt(0);   //delete card delt from shoe
                 }             
            }

             //Display the cards in each of the hands
             for (int i = 0; i < playerHands.hands.Count; i++)
             {
                 Console.Write("Hand {0}: Cards:  ", i);
                 for (int j = 0; j < playerHand.hand.Count; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}{1}, ", playerHands.hands[i].hand [j].rank, playerHands.hands[i].hand[j].suit);               
                }
                 Console.WriteLine();
             }
             Console.Read();
        }
    }
}

    class Hand
    {
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Hand should contain, at a minimum:
    //  A List<> of cards that holds the individual cards delt to a player
    //  Game Number:  A game is continues until the player quits
    //  Hand Number:  Sequential hand played during a game
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public List<Cards> hand;

    public Hand()
    {
        hand = new List<Cards>();
    }

    public void addCard(Cards card)
    {
        this.hand.Add(card);
    }

    public void clearHand()
    {
       hand.Clear(); 
    }
}


class Hands
{
    public List<Hand> hands;

    public Hands()
    {
        hands = new List<Hand>();
    }

    public void addHand(Hand hand)
    {
        hands.Add(hand);
    }
}
```

Comment: ohhh..! Lots of codes. could you please remove irrelevant codes

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I believe that when you are adding the cards to a hand, you are removing the wrong card from the shoe/deck. As you loop 0-4, you grab the jth card from the shoe to put into the hand, but then you remove the top card of the shoe. You want to just add the 0th card, not the jth card.

Comment: It's worth mentioning, that in C# we call methods starting upper case for example AddHand(). Also, Arrays are not depreciated but have a different purpose than Lists. In some cases the performance of Arrays is better. In your case, it's better to use Lists.

Comment: Thanks un-lucky, code was removed.

Comment: Nice catch Gendolkari. changed to: playerHand.addCard(shoe[0]);

Comment: thanks for the info @mikes.  A bit of old-school there where we were taught to name 'functions' with leading  lowercase letters.  Hmmm, is there a good reference as to when to use List vs arrays?

Comment: Mainly optimization. When you have a lot of objects than performing actions on a List can be quite unoptimal. The List has more functions than Array, so Array will make you deal with your data sets more carefully. Lists are just convinient.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is really, really simple: you are not creating enough Hand instances.

You call `Hand  playerHand  = new Hand();` just once.
This means you have only one `Hand` instance, which you are clearing and filling over and over in your first for loop.

You need to call `new Hand()` once for each hand instance (just editing the relevant part of your code):

```
        Hands playerHands = new Hands();

        //Test Hands
        //Create ten hands of dealt cards
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
        {               
            Hand  playerHand = new Hand();
            playerHands.addHand(playerHand);
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
             {
                playerHand.addCard(shoe[j]);
                shoe.RemoveAt(0);   //delete card delt from shoe
             }             
        }
```

Have fun!

Comment: Yeah, I believe I tried that but VS complained: A local or parameter named 'playerHand' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope... I understand what is going on, just cant figure out how to get around it.

Comment: You didn't remove the external declaration. In my snippet, there is no playerHand declaration outside of the for loop

Comment: You can even refactor the for loop in a method InitializePlayerHands, so you restrict the scope of the playerHand local variable. The error message you report simply means you have a playerHands defined somewhere else in the enclosing method. Just name it playerHands2 or something or, better yet, go for multiple, smaller methods.

Comment: Got ya!  I've been going nuts trying to figure this out--so simple.  Thanks!

Comment: If it's working now, mark the answer as answering your question, for future reference (and for reputation ;P).

Comment: As you can tell, I am new here.  Why would I want to answer my own question when you are the one that answered it?